# Editing magento extension

Tags: magento

I have downloaded Youama Ajax Login and Register magento extension.
Its working perfectly.But it has less fields in registration. I want to add more fields in the magento extension like phone no,pincode etc..how to edit magento extension?

Answer (score 0):

Hello check below path & more fields.
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/youama/ajaxlogin/ajaxlogin.phtml

Answer (score 0):

To keep extension more or less upgradeable and do some customization in same time you should copy key .phtml files to your theme folder and do customization over there.

For example copy

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/youama/ajaxlogin/ajaxlogin.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/default/{yourtheme}/template/youama/ajaxlogin/ajaxlogin.phtml

and edit it there (only files you want to edit).

On the other side blocks, models, helpers and controllers should be overridden if customization is needed. You can check overriding process in [this article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) by one of my colleagues.